# Laravel - Redirect::to ou Redirect::back dando erro de TokenMismatchException?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Está acontecendo o seguinte, tenho a tela de login que faz algumas verificações, caso não passe em alguma no meu `Controller` eu faço um `redirect` pra `url` de login com a mensagem de ***erro***.

Aqui é que acontece o ***erro***, após o `redirect` com a mensagem, e eu tento logar novamente está dando `TokenMismatchException`, só para de dar o ***erro*** se eu dou um `refresh` na página.

Já tentei usar:

```
return Redirect::to('login');
```

e

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput();`
```

mas, sem sucesso.

Segue os códigos:

**View**:

```
<form class="sign-in form-horizontal shadow rounded no-overflow" action="{{url('login/doLogin')}}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="E-mail" name="username">
    <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Senha" name="password">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-block no-margin rounded" id="login-btn">Entrar</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Hash;
use Auth;
use Redirect;

class AuthController extends BaseController
{
    public $request = null;
    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    public function doLogin(){
        $erro = "Erro ao logar";
        $requestedUser = $this->request->get('username');
        $requestedPassword = $this->request->get('password');
        $usuario = User::where('email', '=', $requestedUser)->first();
        if ($usuario) {
            if (Hash::check($requestedPassword, $usuario->password)) {
                if (!$usuario->userValidation) {
                    Auth::loginUsingId($usuario->id);
                    $this->toastrMessage("success", 'Logado com sucesso!');
                    return redirect('dashboard');
                }else{
                    $erro = "Acesse o seu e-mail para autenticar sua conta";
                }
            }else{
                $erro = "Senha incorreta";
            }
        }else{
            $erro = "Usuário não encontrado";
        }
        $this->toastrMessage("error", $erro);
        return Redirect::back()->withInput();
        // return Redirect::to('login');
    }
}
```

**Observação¹:** a versão do `Laravel` é a `5.4` e já fiz projetos com versões anteriores do `Laravel` e em nenhum deu esse ***erro***.

**Observação²:** Como uma medida provisória coloquei a rota que faz o login no `except` do `VerifyCsrfToken`.

Comment: Poderia colocar todo o código? só a parte do `Redirect` não diz muita coisa. Seria interessante também a parte da `View`

Comment: Por gentileza, coloque a view também.

Comment: Veja se sua rota 'login' é do tipo `post`. Se for, pode ser esse o motivo do erro.

Comment: Código adicionado. Mas acredito que não seja uma falha do código, pois, como falei, já fiz em versões anteriores  do `laravel` e funcionou tranquilamente.
@VirgilioNovic acredito que você pediu a `view` para saber se eu havia colocado o `{{ csrf_field() }}`. Como pode ver, ele está ali.

Comment: @AmandaLima não, a rota `login` é do tipo `get`

Comment: Porque não utiliza o `FormReques`?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não conheço este `FormReques` poderia me passar algum link sobre o assunto?